# IBM Watson Retrieve and Rank Task are repeating after being completed

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I have two collections in my Retrieve and Rank cluster.

I have already completed TASKS for one collection and trained a ranker for it too.

But, now when am training the second collection, my TASKS' QUESTIONS are repeating. This did not happen when I completed tasks for first collection.

Well, all my respomses are being saved though. But due to repeated questions, teh Ranker Performance Status does not increase.

Even on skipping those questions, the TASK gets started again with same questions.

This is what my Priority Training task looks like, even after being completed:

[image: This is what my Priority Training task looks like, even after being completed]

Eg. PRIORITY TRAINING TASK has 46 question (lets say). After completing the whole task, the PRIORITY TRAINING TASK starts again with the same questions and same recommended answers.

Comment: As this isn't a programming question, but more a report of an issue with an IBM product, it might be better in future to report this sort of thing either within Bluemix's problem reporting or at least at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/

Comment: @dalelane since this issue came while we were training the system, I actually didn't knew if it was due to my mistake or IBM's own fault....hence, wasn't sure of it being a report of an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware that this was happening for some time yesterday as a result of some problems caused by bluemix maintenance -  preventing communication between the question manager and the tasks service.

My understanding is that this was resolved. Please can you try it again and let me know. If it's working now please just mark this as accepted, if it's still a problem add a comment and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But am afraid, this happened again when I tried about an hour ago. What would you recommend me to do now?

Comment: Sorry to hear this. I'm not able to reproduce this myself - I did, of course, test it for myself before posting my answer, and trying again now it still seems to be working for me. 
You can create a support ticket from the Bluemix dashboard (Support -> Add ticket -> Services). Please include the full URL for when you're in the task - as that will include the IDs for both your tenant and the problem task in question.

Comment: can you help me following below query too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743058/how-can-i-build-a-contextual-search-in-my-documents-using-ibm-watson